# From workspace to Simulink

Tags: simulink, workspace

I want to import one matrix 5x5  from  Workspace to Simulink. The software gives me an error: "Invalid workspace variable specified as workspace input in 'MODELLO_From Workspace'. Time values must be non-decreasing." How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use constant block for that.

Here First I created a variable as sample_matris (5x5) in workspace.

```
sample_matris = rand(5,5);
```

Here is the values created in workspace.

[image]

Then I used constant and entered name of the variable defined in workspace.

[image]

You can see that I can use values defined in workspace, by using constant block in simulink. If you need specific indices of the matris, you can use selector block in Simulink.

Comment: Thank you, Yusuf Selim, for your reply.